# Where do I find the Database tool window in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

For a while in PhpStorm I had the Database tool window. This was nice for generating SQL statements and updating the database.

I ended up redownloading it and I can't find the tool window. I went to the documentation and it told me to look here. As you can see there is no Database tool window option.

[image: no database tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have disabled your Database and SQL-Tools perhaps due to a version problem before an upgrade. So go to **"Settings -> Plugins -> Installed"** and search for **"Database Tools and SQL"** perhaps it's missing or disabled.